# Cookie não esta sendo criado

Tags: php, javascript, html

Galera, tenho o seguinte script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.setInterval(function() {
            $(".anuncio iframe").iframeTracker({
                blurCallback: function() {
                    console.log("blurCallback!");
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        <?php setcookie("Changed","Ok", time() + 172800,  $path = "/"); ?>
                        liberar();
                   }, 2000);
                }
            }); 
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

A função "liberar" do script chega a ser executada, mas por alguma razão o cookie não esta sendo criado. Quando coloco o cookie logo acima do head ai cria, mas se eu deixar dentro desse script ele não cria, como se o script pulasse a criação do cookie e fosse direto executar a função "liberar". Poderia me ajudar a entender por que o cookie não esta sendo criado?

Comment: Um código PHP é executado no servidor uma única vez. Colocar ele ali dentro do setTimeout não tem efeito nenhum dentro do JavaScript. Se vc olhar o código-fonte da página verá que onde vc colocou `<?php setcookie("Changed","Ok", time() + 172800,  $path = "/"); ?>` está vazio.

Comment: Mas tipo, minha intenção é que crie somente uma unica vez mesmo? Só não entendo pq o script funciona, chama a função "liberar", mas pula a criação do cookie.

Comment: Então não faz sentido colocar o código justamente ali no meio do JavaScript.

Comment: Então onde eu deveria colocar? Poderia me dar uma luz? Eu estou tentando criar o cookie no momento em que ocorrer um clique em um iframe. A verificação do iframe funciona, ele ativa a função "liberar", só o cookie que não esta criando realmente.

Comment: A comunicação entre JavaScript e o PHP é feita por AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde caro, tenho uma sugestão.

primeiro crie o seguinte arquivo php

```
 //arquivo setCookie.php
 <?php
 setcookie("Changed","Ok", time() + 172800,  $path = "/");
 echo 1;
```

agora com o jquery relacione o evento desejado ao elemento

```
 <script>
 $(document).on("click", ".anuncio iframe", function(){
      setCookie();
 });
 </script>
```

Esse trecho faz com que o evento "click" ( ou qualquer evento) e o elemento  ".anuncio iframe" estejam relacionados a qualquer tempo, independente de se o elemento já foi carregado ou não. Chamando então a função setCookie() descrita na sequencia

```
function setCookie(){
        $.ajax({
                url:"setCookie.php",
                success:function(data){
                        if(data == 1){
                        console.log("ok")
                        }
                }
        });
}
```

E voilá! para conferir se deu certo abra o inspetor (F12) e veja no console o ok, veja também em aplication os cookies, abraços

Caso prefira copiar e colar:

```
 <script>
 $(document).on("click", ".anuncio iframe", function(){
       $.ajax({
                url:"setCookie.php",
                success:function(data){
                        if(data == 1){
                        console.log("ok")
                        }
                }
        });
 });
 </script>
```

ou

```
<script>
function setCookie(){
        $.ajax({
                url:"setCookie.php",
                success:function(data){
                        if(data == 1){
                        console.log("ok")
                        }
                }
        });
}
$(document).on("click", ".anuncio iframe", function(){
     setCookie();
});
</script>
```

Vale ressaltar que onde se lê "click", pode ser substituído por qualquer manipulador de evento como listados no link 
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events

Comment: Show, cara. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

É mais simples substituir o trecho `<?php setcookie("Changed","Ok", time() + 172800,  $path = "/"); ?>` por uma função nativa da linguagem javascript:

```
document.cookie = "Changed=ok";
```

Com isso você criará o cookie. Caso queira adicionar mais parâmetros ao cookie acesse [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: Valeu, cara. Vou tentar essa alternativa

Comment: Deu certo a sugestão?